# How do you convert an string into an integer in SwiftUI?

Tags: string, swiftui, type-conversion, integer

I am trying to make a simple calculator using SwiftUI, but one thing frustrates me. For reference, here is the minimum reproducible example:

```
    @State var enteredNumber: String = "" // This is the user input in a string form
    @State var usable number: Int = Int(enteredNumber) // I thought this would work but it doesn't.
```

I found this on hackingwithswift.com, and I thought it would work. I also looked my problem up in stack overflow, but I can't seem to understand any of the questions (I'm sorta new to SwiftUI). The approach I used just gave me an error saying:

Cannot use instance member 'enteredNumber' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

and

Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Int'

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: where on `hackingwithswift.com` did you find this?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int

Comment: that is not what you show us. The first error tells you that you cannot use a variable before it is initialized.
Meaning you cannot use `enteredNumber` in `Int(enteredNumber)` . 
This understanding is fundamental to using swift, so read up on how to initialize structs.

The second error tells you, `Int(enteredNumber)` returns a Int?, but you want Int,
which is different. This understanding is also fundamental to using swift.

In other words do some basic study of swift. Also there must be no space in var name,  `@State var usablenumber: Int = Int(enteredNumber)`

Comment: Oh. Thanks for telling me.